# IProgress notification in MVC model

Tags: c#, async-await, iprogress

I have started using IProgress with async/await in my MVC application (desktop) but I'm a bit confused about the design of the whole thing.

I have a form/view V which starts the action of downloading data. V, will call the controller C to start the download/request the data, which in turn will call the Model M to start the actual download (from a webservice or whatever data source).

Now I want M to notify V(iew) whenever there's a progress update in the download. For this, the notification should go through C:

V-->C-->M  then  M-->C-->V

Using IProgress, I should send an IProgress implementation from V all the way to M. And the notifications should trigger from there. All the examples I've seen have only 2 classes/layers that make a simple implementation.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: I think of IProgress as just a fancy binding - and that the controller was done with its chores when it brought the model and view together.  I don't know why it would have to participate in the data exchange.